# Cannot upgrade Mongodb Replica Set from 3.6 -> 4.0 (Wire versions a incompatible)

Tags: mongodb

i have a productive mongodb replica set (3 members) running in version 3.6. As the title expects, i want to upgrade to version 4.0. I have followed the instructions here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.0-upgrade-replica-set/
So setFeatureCompatibilityVersion is set to "3.6" and replica set protocol version already was set to pv1.
The instructions sad to shut down a member, upgrade Binaries, restart and reconnect to the replica set. One by one with every replica set member.

I have modified this workflow a bit. Instead of shutting down a member i simply want to add a fourth member running version 4.0 to the set. After the initial sync is finished i want to drop an old member from the set. then adding the next member running version 4.0, drop the next old member an so on.

I already used this technique when i was upgrading from version 3.4 to 3.6 and it works fine.

Now the actually problem:

I add the fourth member with version 4.0 to my 3.6 replica set with
`rs.add("serverip")` and command sad "ok".
But when i lookup the replica set status the new member is **"(not reachable/healthy)"** and the last Heartbeat Message sad **"Server min and max wire version are incompatible (7,7) with client min wire version (6,6)"**

What iam doing wrong here? I dont find many information about the "wire verions" and by what they are influenced or configured. So how do i "upgrade" these wire versions in my existing replica set to 7 or how can i force the new version 4.0 member to use version 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wire version is basically a different way of representing the server version. 6 is 3.6, 7 is 4.0.

What the message is telling you is that the client (I assume the internal client in the server that talks to the other nodes) requires the server to be exactly 3.6.

This is a bit weird message to me in that during the binary replacement, you should have some nodes with wire version 6 and some with 7. Maybe FCV somehow gets accounted for differently.

In any event, **you cannot add a 4.0 node because it has FCV set to 4.0 and all your other nodes have 3.6 FCV**. If you want to add a new node you should add it with a 3.6 binary, sync data to it while your RS is in 3.6, then perform the upgrade following the stated instructions with the extra node.

Comment: Alternately, you can start up your 4.0 node as a standalone (without the replset config options), manually set its FCV to "3.6", then shutdown, reconfigure with the replica set information, and restart.  That will allow the 3.6 nodes to talk to it.